# Как валидировать IP?

Tags: php, валидация

Как сделать проверку айпи в строке к примеру 127.0.0.1 верный а 054.24.01.af.53 неверный или 1.2.3 неверный. Помогите

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`filter_var`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.filter-var.php) с флагом [`FILTER_VALIDATE_IP`](http://php.net/manual/ru/filter.filters.flags.php):

```
$valid = filter_var($string, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP);
```

Если нужно разрешить только ipv4, то:

```
$valid = filter_var($string, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP, FILTER_FLAG_IPV4);
```